# Truncate json from Apple app site association as a static file in Angular via AWS

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-association

I was able to setup the `.well-known/apple-app-site-association` correctly via angular static files and it already works correctly but i have to do it manually. Here's what I currently do:

1. save and serve the json file in angular without a file extension

```
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/.well-known",
                "output": ".well-known"
              }
```

2. open S3 and find apple-app-site-association > edit metadata to application/json

My problem is it always reverts to `binary/octet` everytime I deploy. I was hoping theres a way to force the file to be a json file? OR retain the .json file extension `apple-app-site-association.json` but truncate when it is accessed? https://example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

Not sure if this is an S3/cloudfront/anything AWS or angular fixed